# I want to test postgres database using selenium

Tags: postgresql, selenium

I successfully integrate the postgres and eclipse but unable to test the database. I need to know where can i get help if any suggestions would be appreciate.By the way i am using java. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by test database using selenium?

Comment: Mean database testing using selenium. If i want test the duplicates in the list of records i will write test code in selenium using java.

Comment: I'm not sure you are able to accomplish that using selenium. Selenium framework is for UI test not for DB test. You have to write your test manually using JUnit or other test unit test framework.

Comment: I found some documents which explains the selenium database testing for Oracle and mySQL etc.. But i want to access the postgres database and test the data for my tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium is not the right tool here, as it is a tool for automating testing of web front-ends.  You cannot directly test your database using this tool.

You can test an application like phppgadmin, but it isn't clear that is what you want.

A better approach is just to write test cases through jUnit and jdbc, in my view.  That gives you better control and testing than you can via a web front-end and it is easier to solve the question of whether you want transactions to rollback or not (selenium poses this problem since it is indirect and tests a web app that interacts with the db over a stateless connection).